# Change Firefox Extension Directory

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-addon, environment-variables, search-path

The path where Firefox looks for Plugins can easily be changed using [the `MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH` environment variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Plugins/Guide/Plug-in_Basics#Linux).

Does such a facility also exist for [Add-Ons (also called extensions)](https://addons.mozilla.org/)? Similar to how `MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH` changes `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`, I am searching for a way to change `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/`.

Comment: I was trying to change the path where firefox updates into. Ill show you what I came up with, it didn't work. But it might for you.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the udpate directory of Firefox, I was not succesful, but here is my attempt, I think everything else was successfully overriden. If you figure out how to override update directory please share :)

[OSX - Change special paths, especialy folder to which update is delivered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304040/osx-change-special-paths-especialy-folder-to-which-update-is-delivered)

Here is an example of me actually using it - https://github.com/Noitidart/Profilist/blob/mac-iconing-alpha/bootstrap.js#L6470-L6563